# How do I get a random number to only be utilized once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After a random number has been selected, is it possible to go into the first `if` statement only once and skip it every other time that number is selected?

```
int Randomizer;
int Random1;
int Random2;

public void RandomButton()
{
    Randomizer = Random.Range(1,3);

    if (Randomizer == 1)
    {
        Random1 = 1;
        Debug.Log("First Value");

        if (Random1 == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Nested Value");
        }
    }

    if (Randomizer == 2)
    {
        Debug.Log("Second Value");

        if (Random2 == 2)
        {
            Debug.Log("Nested Value");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you format your code a little better, so that the lines are better aligned vertically?

Comment: What I mean is the "First Value" is discarded after first use and the second use it will only use the "Nested Value" in random==1 instead of "First Value" :))

Comment: It doesn't appear you ever set `Random2` to anything. And in the first case, you are setting `Random1 = 1` just before you check for that condition, so it will always be `true`.

Comment: ops sorry wrong comment hehe I meant in randomizer==1 it will use "First Value" and after it randomizer==1 again instead of "First Value" it will only use "Nested Value" not the "First Value" again

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ops sorry guys for misleading question but I found out just now hehe peace :)) what I want to achieve is that

```
  int Randomizer;
  int Random1;
  int Random2;

  public void RandomButton()
   {
        Randomizer = Random.Range(1,3);
        if (Randomizer ==1)          
              Random1 += 1;
          if (Random1==1)        
              Debug.Log("Nested Value 1");
          if (Random1==2)
              Debug.Log("Nested Value 2");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

If you want to only utilize a random number once, I would save this kind of information into a better data structure like a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1). This has the property to only contain unique numbers. You can utilize the nature of this data structure so you do not have to create variables for every random number you want to collect.

```
using System.Collections.Generic

HashSet<int> RandomNumbersUsed = new HashSet<int>();

public void RandomButton()
{
    int randomNumber = Random.Range(1,3);

    if (!RandomNumbersUsed.Contains(randomNumber))
    {
        // Add it to the HashSet so that it cannot be used again
    }
    else
    {
        // Tell the user that the random has been selected before
    }

    if (randomNumber == 1)
    {
        // Do processing when random == 1
    }

    if (randomNumber == 2)
    {
        // Do processing when random == 2
    }

    // Continue adding necessary random numbers
}
```

---

### Original

You're looking for [`if-else`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) block.

```
if (Random == 1)
{ ... }

else if (Random == 2)
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to output one thing the first time a number is chosen, and something else for each subsequent time the same number is chosen. If that's correct, I think the easiest way to do this using your existing code is to assign the valud of `Random1` inside the `else` block of a nested `if/else` statement that checks the value of `Random1`. This way you only assign it once:

```
public void RandomButton()
{
    Randomizer = Random.Range(1, 3);

    if (Randomizer == 1)
    {
        if (Random1 == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Nested   Value");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("First Value");
            Random1 = 1;
        }
    }

    // Repeat the same pattern for the other number here...
}
```